# Посоветуйте Лемматизатор, хорошо разбирающий фамилии (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, поиск-библиотек, nlp

Пытаюсь разобрать этот список на леммы:

```
['Динамика', 'возобновления', 'роста', 'случаев', 'коронавируса', 'COVID-19', 'в',
 'мире', 'является', 'поводом', 'для', 'серьезной', 'обеспокоенности', '–', 'признал',
 'преcс-секретарь', 'президента', 'России', 'Дмитрий', 'Песков', '.']
```

Это:

```
import pymorphy2
morph = pymorphy2.MorphAnalyzer()
for word in for_lemma:
    print(word, [p.normal_form for p in morph.parse(word)])
```

Дает:

```
Песков ['песок']
```

Это:

```
import spacy
sample_sentences = "Динамика возобновления роста случаев коронавируса COVID-19 в мире является поводом для серьезной обеспокоенности – признал преcс-секретарь президента России Дмитрий Песков."
if __name__ == '__main__':
    nlp = spacy.load('ru2', disable=['tagger', 'parser', 'NER'])
    nlp.add_pipe(nlp.create_pipe('sentencizer'), first=True)
    doc = nlp(sample_sentences)
    for s in doc.sents:
        print(list(['lemma "{}" from text "{}"'.format(t.lemma_, t.text) for t in s]))
```

Тоже дает "песок".

DeepPavlov пробовал разобраться, но что-то очень сложный. Если DeepPavlov, могли бы привести пример простого кода.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть же библиотека [Наташа](https://github.com/natasha/natasha). Я вам пример набросал по [документации](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/natasha/natasha/blob/master/docs.ipynb), надеюсь дальше разберётесь, как приспособить под ваши нужды:

```
#pip install natasha

from natasha import (
    Segmenter,
    MorphVocab,
    
    NewsEmbedding,
    NewsMorphTagger,
    NewsSyntaxParser,
    NewsNERTagger,
    
    PER,
    NamesExtractor,
    DatesExtractor,
    MoneyExtractor,
    AddrExtractor,

    Doc
)

text = "Динамика возобновления роста случаев коронавируса COVID-19 в мире является поводом для серьезной обеспокоенности – признал преcс-секретарь президента России Дмитрий Песков."

segmenter = Segmenter()
morph_vocab = MorphVocab()

emb = NewsEmbedding()
morph_tagger = NewsMorphTagger(emb)
syntax_parser = NewsSyntaxParser(emb)
ner_tagger = NewsNERTagger(emb)

names_extractor = NamesExtractor(morph_vocab)
dates_extractor = DatesExtractor(morph_vocab)
money_extractor = MoneyExtractor(morph_vocab)
addr_extractor = AddrExtractor(morph_vocab)

doc = Doc(text)
doc.segment(segmenter)
doc.tag_morph(morph_tagger)
doc.parse_syntax(syntax_parser)
doc.tag_ner(ner_tagger)

for token in doc.tokens:
    token.lemmatize(morph_vocab)
    
display({_.text: _.lemma for _ in doc.tokens})

for span in doc.spans:
    span.normalize(morph_vocab)
    
display({_.text: _.normal for _ in doc.spans})
```

Вывод:

```
{'.': '.',
 'COVID-19': 'covid-19',
 'c': 'c',
 'Динамика': 'динамика',
 'Дмитрий': 'дмитрий',
 'Песков': 'песков',
 'России': 'россия',
 'в': 'в',
 'возобновления': 'возобновление',
 'для': 'для',
 'коронавируса': 'коронавирус',
 'мире': 'мир',
 'обеспокоенности': 'обеспокоенность',
 'поводом': 'повод',
 'пре': 'пре',
 'президента': 'президент',
 'признал': 'признать',
 'роста': 'рост',
 'с-секретарь': 'с-секретарь',
 'серьезной': 'серьезный',
 'случаев': 'случай',
 'является': 'являться',
 '–': '–'}

{'Дмитрий Песков': 'Дмитрий Песков', 'России': 'Россия'}
```

Вам обязательно надо разбирать предложения целиком, никакая библиотека по одному слову без контекста не сможет понять, что перед ней - фамилия человека или слово в каком-то падеже. Только предложения, только контекст. `Наташа` разбирает именно предложения.

Хотя тут тоже какая-то лажа с словосочетанием `преcс-секретарь`, но в целом то выглядит неплохо.

Comment: Отличная вещь. Спасибо. Особенно, если разобраться во всем доп. функционале. По поводу решения проблем с фамилиями в pymorphy, есть доработка для DeepPavlov, но я так и не понял, как её внедрить. https://github.com/deepmipt/DeepPavlov/pull/1279. Возможно, у кого-то получится.

Comment: @AlexIvanov Я с `DeepPavlov` пока не разбирался. Да, его хвалят, но руки пока не доходили. Для чат-ботов его очень рекомендовали, да и вообще.